# CLI to copy to clipboard but still output to term ?

Tags: terminal, command-line, copy-paste

I know that piping to `pbcopy` copies command line outputs to the clipboard.

How can I still show the output in the terminal ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tool of choice is called `tee`. Full description is available via `man tee` but you canprobably just use

```
echo test | tee >(pbcopy)
```

to get the result you are looking for.

Comment: i'd love to understand why `>(command)` does this.

Comment: @MaxCascone See `man bash`, "Process Substitution".

Answer (score 2):

You could just pbpaste immediately after.
`echo test | pbcopy | pbpaste`